# Windows batch : find string contains another string inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file, webp

I am trying to convert a set of PNG images to WEBP images using cwebp encoder.
I managed to do it using a JAVA program but now I want to write a batch file to do this task.
I already got **metal03326's** [solution](http://metal03326.blogspot.kr/2012/05/converting-multiple-files-into-webp.html) after some searching.
But I want one modification in this that 9 patch images should be skipped.

Here is what I did :

```
pushd %1

set "DOTNINE=.9"

echo %DOTNINE%

for /f "delims=" %%n in ('dir /b /s /a-d-h-s') do (

set MY=%%~nn

set MY=%MY:~-2%

rem IF NOT ".webp" == "%%~xn" IF NOT "MY" == ".9" ("%~dp0cwebp.exe" -q 80 "%%n" -o "%%n.webp") ELSE (echo File already WEBP.)

)

popd
```

But I'm getting a syntax error. What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: No syntax error shown here on Win 7. Is it the entire batch script?

Comment: Removed the `android` tag, since this question has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-assign a variable (namely `MY`) multiple times in a loop you have to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%n in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do (
    set MY=%%~nn
    set MY=!MY:~-2!
    IF NOT ".webp" == "%%~xn" IF NOT "!MY!" == ".9" ("%~dp0cwebp.exe" -q 80 "%%n" -o "%%n.webp") ELSE (echo File already WEBP.)
)
popd
```

Comment: Thanks! It did the job :)
One more thing - Is there a way to do this at one place i.e instead of creating MY variable do it in IF NOT condition ?

Comment: `set "MY=%%~nn" & set "MY=!MY:~-2!" & IF .....`, for example. Another method would be to use `for /f`.